# Comment edit history popup is not fully visible in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, design, moderator-tools

♦ moderators have the ability to see the edit history of comments. However, the popup is badly aligned, so part of the text isn't visible:

[image]

Tested on Firefox 58.0.2 on macOS 10.13.3; it doesn't happen on Safari.

Somehow, the dismissable message element gets a large negative `left` property; if I disable that, it's displaying fine. The `top` property is off as well, it seems.

[image]

Comment: Having the same issue with Firefox 58.0.2. on Windows 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed in the next build, thanks!