# Can moderators see a version history of comments?

Tags: support, comments, moderator-tools

I think it is well known that only moderators can see [deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232094/why-can-only-mods-see-deleted-comments) comments.

But what I am wondering (mainly out of pure curiosity): can moderators also see the "edit history" of comments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Yes, we can](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307404/295232).

> [image]

Comment: Which makes a lot of sense, but now I am wondering how one of those high-traffic Q/As on MSE looks to the moderators. Not only deleted comments, but also version history for all (?) comments then. Must be a real mess ....

Comment: We don't see them immediately, we have to click the 'pencil' icon (which is visible to all users when a comment is edited).

Comment: @GhostCat Version history for comments is only available if you specifically click to look at it. It doesn't make the whole page a mess.